# iBeacon monitoring in background

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I read that iOS7.1 was supposed to have fixed iBeacon monitoring in the background. I am seeing that it takes about 15 minutes for a monitored beacon to call the didExitRegion while in the background, regardless of what background capabilities I add. This makes it rather unusable for my scenario.

Is there any way to get more frequent updates? Short of that, are there any other ways to keep my app alive in background so that I get more frequent monitoring and possibly even ranging?

Comment: What you are describing is still the case AFAIK - http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background detection times still take up to 15 minutes on iOS 7.1**, especially on older models like the iPhone 4S.  I did tests to demonstrate this, which you can read about here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html

**It is possible to keep your app alive in the background** so these detectuons are faster, but unless you have a navigation or audio app, allowing app store approval for special background modes, **you are limited to 3 minutes of background activity at a time**.  See here for details: 
http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html